# Securely receiving log messages with logstash

Tags: security, logging, logstash, filebeat

I am currently working with logstash. I want to receive logs from hundreds of clients. I need to produce an output consolidated log that contains a "client_id" field .

The issue is that I need to prevent one client from impersonating another. In other words, that I want  clients to authenticate, and to force the client_id field of the messages to match the authenticated user.

Alternatively, I would want to mutate the messages to add a "client_id" attribute based on the authenticated user.

Can this be achieved with logstash ? If not , what other technology do you recommend ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do look into the lumberjack protocol and use a certificate per client and on top of that each client will have a different port, so you can add additional firewall rules only allowing data from the correct source ips to go to these ports